# Problems with SmartToolbar not recreating fragments

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm having a problem with this SmartToolbar, if I open the app and click on the chat or book icon it opens perfectly and shows the fragments, but if I click on another icon to open another fragment, when I go back to them they don't show more The fragments that should be on the smartToolbar, as shown in the prints below, bug everything! I need to help on this as soon as possible !!!

[Opens normally  [When I click on another item and go back to it, it no longer opens the SmartToolbar fragments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTiso.jpg)here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwweO.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2cXi.jpg)

I will send the homeAcitivity code, where is the layout that opens the fragments of the buttonNavigationBar

`class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {`

```
var MY_ACCOUNT = 1
var LIBRARY = 2
var HOME = 3
var CHAT = 4
var SETTINGS = 5

private var Content: ConstraintLayout? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    supportActionBar!!.hide()

    nav.show(HOME)

    nav.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    abrirHome()

    addOnMeowNavigattionBarIcons()
    addOnNotificationInform()

    chamarFragments()

}

fun abrirHome() {
    val fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
    addFragment(fragment)
}

fun addOnMeowNavigattionBarIcons() {
    nav.add(MeowBottomNavigation.Model(MY_ACCOUNT, R.drawable.ic_baseline_account_circle_24))
    nav.add(MeowBottomNavigation.Model(LIBRARY, R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_book_24))
    nav.add(MeowBottomNavigation.Model(HOME, R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_24))
    nav.add(MeowBottomNavigation.Model(CHAT, R.drawable.ic_baseline_chat_24))
    nav.add(MeowBottomNavigation.Model(SETTINGS, R.drawable.ic_baseline_settings_24))
}

fun addOnNotificationInform() {
    nav.setCount(CHAT, "99")
}

fun chamarFragments() {
    nav.setOnClickMenuListener {

        when (it.id) {
            HOME -> {
                val fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
                addFragment(fragment)
            }

            MY_ACCOUNT -> {
                val fragment = MyAccountFragment.newInstance()
                addFragment(fragment)
            }

            LIBRARY -> {
                val fragment = LibraryFragment.newInstance()
                addFragment(fragment)

            }

            CHAT -> {
                val fragment = ChatFragment.newInstance()
                addFragment(fragment)
            }

            SETTINGS -> {
                val fragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance()
                addFragment(fragment)
            }

        }
    }
}

private fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.parentfragments,fragment,fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
}

fun sair(view: View){
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
    val bundle = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle()
    val intent = Intent(this, login::class.java)
    startActivity(intent,bundle)
}
```

}

This is the code of the fragment Library that has a SmartToolbar that calls two more fragments within it, MyLibrary and Store

`class LibraryFragment: Fragment() {`

```
companion object{
    fun newInstance():LibraryFragment {
        val args = Bundle()
        val fragment = LibraryFragment()
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.library_fragment, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    val adapter = FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
        fragmentManager, FragmentPagerItems.with(context)
            .add("Minha Bilioteca", MyLibraryFragment::class.java)
            .add("Loja", StoreFragment::class.java)
            .create())
    viewpager.adapter = adapter
    viewpagertab.setViewPager(viewpager)

}
```

}

And this is the MyLibrary fragment that is shown inside the Library that is shown inside HomeActivity

`class MyLibraryFragment: Fragment() {`

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylibrary_fragment, container, false)
}
```

}